# How to connect more USB devices to a laptop?

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, lenovo-laptop

My new laptop **(Lenovo b50-30 using Windows 8.1, with three USB ports)** can not connect more than 14 USB devices. How can I get more connected to this laptop?

I have 70 pcs of DSLR Сanon. When I connect them to a desktop computer - no problem. When I connect it to **another** laptop - no problem.
I connect through a ten-port hubs with external power supplies. Consistently including cameras, one by one, it does not matter in what order; after 14 devices, I get an error about reaching the limit and lack of resources.

Comment: One sentence questions do not contain enough detail for anyone to help. Please [edit] this to contain more detail like; What is the actual problem? Are you getting error messages? No place to connect them? Are the devices connected, but not working?

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm apologize! I have 70 DSLR canon. When I connect it to a desktop computer - no problem. 
When I connect it to another laptop - no problem. 
I connect through a ten-port active hubs. 
Consistently including cameras, one by one, it does not matter in what order, after 14 device error takes about reaching the limit and lack of resources. Apologize for bad English!

Comment: I can't find any detailed info on your PC on the internet. Please download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/cpu-z/1.70-setup-en.exe), install and run it, go into the `About` tab, and click `Save Report (.TXT)` Then paste it into [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) and post the link here. After that we'll be able to view detailed information about your specific PC and see if there are any limitations built in.

On a side note, if you ever want to view information about your PC, you can use CPU-Z. It's a really good tool.

Comment: Data on the Lenovo B50-30 is at http://www.zdnet.com/lenovo-b50-30-first-take-a-windows-notebook-at-a-chromebook-price-point-7000032376/ and http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-b-series-laptops/lenovo-b50-30-notebook

Comment: @Jonah http://pastebin.com/8AhUGC0L - New laptops CPU-Z data with this issue. http://pastebin.com/c4vRcHnF - old laptop, who working fine!

Comment: Well there's nothing on either report to indicate lack of USB functionality, and as you've already pointed out, it's not a power issue if it works on another system. Is it possible to take the memory cards out of the cameras and use them, or do they all run on internal memory?

Comment: @Jonah Unfortunately they are working on sd cards, and I have not  so many card readers. :( Maybe another version of windows, like on old laptop (win 7) can help me?

Comment: If it is an error with windows specifically, then you may be able to get around it by [running a linux operating system in a virtual machine](http://lifehacker.com/233230/beginners-guide-to-running-linux-in-a-virtual-machine), then using that to copy the data onto your windows disk/NAS/etc. Seems unlikely, though.

Comment: Is the laptop plugged in too?

Answer (score 2):

Kanistra, USB flash drives and other devices can vary in the amount of power they use, so you might replace some of the more power hungry drives with more efficient ones. The camera could be very power hungry, so I would make sure it goes on a USB 3.0 port which can deliver [up to 900ma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0) of power, instead of the 500ma limit of USB 2.0 ports.  Your machine has three USB ports; one or two will be USB 2.0 (black connector), and the remainder will be USB 3.0 (blue connector).

Since a standard laptop USB port only provides a maximum of [500ma @ 5VDC](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7871688_standard-usb-power-output.html), the total power consumption of everything you have plugged in is using more power than available.

If you need to go mobile, you can buy a [powered hub](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Apowered%20usb%20hub) and make a [four each AA battery pack](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062253) or buy an [external rechargable battery pack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008YRG5JQ) for it, plus the right cable required to fit the power socket of the hub. Hubs all use 5 VDC in, but the maximum milliamp rating of the battery pack (or power supply) determines how much power can be delivered to the hub, and the milliamp-hour rating of the pack will determine how long the devices can be powered on that hub.

Comment: Thank you! Devices are connected through a ten-port hubs **with external power supplies.**

Comment: but.. on another laptop they are working very fine!

Comment: Other laptops can be designed to provide more power. Even seemingly identical laptops of the same model can deliver differing amounts of power to the USB ports because of a) different components used b) changes in the design mid-run c) aging of the USB power regulators inside.

Comment: OK. You still might be maxing out the hub power supply. Each power supply should have a rating on it, _which may or may not be accurate_, in milliamps of capacity. The hub draws some power itself, leaving the rest for devices. . .  You might try finding a power supply with the same plug, but more capacity, to see if the power supply of the hub is inadequate to the task. . . . Also, you might have a ham radio operator or someone else adept at electricity put a multimeter or ammeter in series with the power supply and measure the amperage draw of each device, to see where the big offenders are.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum USB devices you can connect is 127. Get a bunch of USB hubs and connect away.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but of course I'm doing it through the USB hubs. I connect three hub in different usb ports, but when more than 14 devices, windows displays a message on the limitation.

Comment: @Nikita - Sounds like these USB Hubs are not powered by external power supplies, if that's the case, there isn't anything you can do to get more then 14 devices powered by USB connected to your system.

Comment: @Nikita If your hubs are powered externally and you still have this issue, you need to rephrase the question to reflect a good description of the correct setup.

Comment: @Ramhound On another laptop, it works fine on the same hubs!

Comment: Other laptops can be designed to provide more power. Even seemingly identical laptops of the same model can deliver differing amounts of power to the USB ports because of a) different components used b) changes in the design mid-run c) aging of the USB power regulators inside.

Comment: The other laptop has 2 separate hubs powered independently from one another

Comment: @Ramhound I also tried to connect the hub to hub. On an old laptop, it works fine, but on a new laptop - the same issue after 14 device.

Comment: You are using hubs with external power supplies if not try that I guarantee doing so will allow more than 14 devices

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using hubs with external power supplies, which are very fine worked on another laptop and desktop computer!

Comment: Without knowing how many internal hubs both computers have I cant help.